# How many ways does Unix feign files?

Tags: unix, filesystems, pipe, named-pipe

I know Unix filesystem sometimes has things that appear to be files but are not actually files.  The files in `dev` actually point to devices.  Its also possible to created named pipes which also appear to be files but are actually fifo message queues of sorts.  The `proc` directory has files based on processes, memory, hardware, etc.

I am trying to better to understand these abstractions to decide which I might be able to utilize.  How many ways does Unix feign files and which can be readily implemented/used by admins?  (i.e. named pipes and symlinks are easy enough to use.)  If I knew the right terms for the concepts I might be able to find the details online.

Comment: Along with named pipes, there are also sockets. A list of some of the differences between the two here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475442/unix-domain-socket-vs-named-pipes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types should give you a preliminary way of the types of files in Unix. Seems like there are 7 types in all:

- - (regular file)
- d (directory)
- l (symbolic link)
- b (block device)
- c (character device)
- p (named pipe)
- s (socket)

There's more information regarding these file types in some old (and apparently obsolete) Debian documentation: http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-tutorial/ch-advanced.html

But as for more modern references, I don't know of any off the top of my head.